# Hybris: Child user group not visible in Promotion User Restriction

Tags: parent-child, sap-commerce-cloud, promotions

I created a parent user group and a child user group through storefront.

```
eg: ROOT >>
            PARENT >>
                      CHILD
```

When I see the User Restriction screen of Promotions in Product Cockpit, then I can only see parent user groups ROOT and PARENT and not child user group CHILD. Am I missing something? The user group are of type B2Unit.

PS: I cannot post this question in Hybris forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this issue was because of a personalization rule added in HMC for the product manager group. The personalization rule allowed only the ROOT group and immediate children of the ROOT group to be displayed on the User Restriction screen of Promotion in Product Cockpit. I updated this filter.